# Get json from php session instead of json file

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have this jquery function

```
function updateStatus(){
      $.getJSON("<?php echo $_SESSION['filnavn']; ?>", function(data){

                           var items = [];

                           pbvalue = 0;

                           if(data){

                                var total = data['total'];
                                var current = data['current'];
                                var pbvalue = Math.floor((current / total) * 100);

                                if(pbvalue>0){

                                    $("#progressbar").progressbar({

                                        value:pbvalue
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                            if(pbvalue < 100){

                               t = setTimeout("updateStatus()", 500);
                            }
      });
}
```

Is it possible to get the JSON from a PHP session variable instead of a json file?

As I have understood I can get the session data from the session like this:

```
//json test
var jsonstr = $_SESSION['json_status'];
//parse json
var data = JSON.parse(jsonstr);
```

But I do not know how I can do that with out the getJSON function?

Comment: Not a solution, but don't *ever* pass strings to `setTimeout`.  It uses `eval`!  Pass a function: `t = setTimeout(updateStatus, 500);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet here is to create a php file that can act as the target of getJSON that returns the json from your session.

```
 <?php
 session_start();
 if (isset($_SESSION["filnavn"])){
     echo $_SESSION["filnavn"];
     // Or, if the key contains an object instead of a json string, use
     // echo json_encode($_SESSION["filavn"]);
 } else {
     // echo the json you want here if the session variable is not set 
     echo "{}";
 }
 ?>
```

Then in your jquery code change the getJSON to this

```
  $.getJSON("/path/to/php/file.php", function(data){...});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're reading too much into it. .getjson is just a $.ajax() call that EXPECTS to get a json reponse from the server. That's all.

It doesn't matter **WHERE** PHP gets data from, as long as it spits out json text.

Whether that json text was just retrieved from a file/db, or dynamically generated with json_encode(), as long as the browser receives json text, things will "work".